# Get PID of new process

Tags: regex, perl, background-process, pid

So I'm creating a process in Perl like this:

```
my $process = `nohup ./run > /dev/null 2>&1 &`;
```

Which returns something along the lines of

```
[1] 2905
```

How do I go about getting the process ID from this so later on in the script execution I can run something like:

```
exec("kill -9 $pid");
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
/\[1\] ([0-9]+)/g
```

but it looks quite messy, is there any way to improve upon this regular expression? Will that regex always work? Is there any case where it wont be `[1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
@ar  = split(/\s+/, $process);
$pid = $ar[1];
```

Comment: I guess that would work, thanks! I've upvoted and will accept in 5 minutes once I can, that's if there isn't a better answer.

Comment: After testing, I updated it to two lines, as I couldn't get the original one-liner to work.

Comment: I was having some problems with that, too. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like '`' doesn't work to capture output. Do you know why?

Comment: The backtick operator captures and returns the programs STDOUT. How are you trying to use it?

Comment: I'm running the command `nohup echo test >/dev/null 2>&1 &` using the backtick operator, which in my terminal returns `[1] 3132` yet if I print the contents of the capture, it returns nothing.

Comment: @mattexx The "one-liner (`slice`)" wasn't working because you needed parens around the `split` function. Eg `$rv = (split /\s/, $line)[$i];`

Comment: @chrsblck thanks I did figure that out after the fact. Been using python for a while, and had some language confusion. :-)

Comment: Anyone got the answer to my question or should I make a new question?

Comment: I think this qualifies as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using a "fork and exec" pattern here.

```
if (my $pid = fork()) {
  # You're in the parent process
  # $pid contains the PID of the new child process
  ...
} else {
  # You're in the new child process
  # exec() your new command
  exec($cmd);
  # Execution never gets here
}
```

**Edit:** Actually, given that you're basically creating a daemon process here, perhaps you should look at [Proc::Daemon](https://metacpan.org/module/Proc%3a%3aDaemon) instead.